# function Mootools & Ajax to POST date to form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, mootools

My first question :)

I am using Mootools and i have a JavaScript function, my issue is how to post data to form without refreshing the page.

I think that my code is not working with Mootools, Please check and advise

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function (PostData) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form.php",
            data: { userid: 1111, test: 'test'}
        })
    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should read [Mootools documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core) . If you want to make it that way, use jQuery. I think Mootools implementation for ajax call is named as Request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was already stated. the $.ajax method is a Jquery method. If you want to do it in mootools you should use the Request Class.

Here's [the Mootools request documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request) in case you want (and should) dig a little deeper.

Here's what you want to achieve using Mootools

```
var request = new Request({
    url: 'form.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        userId:1111,
        test: 'test'
    },
    onSuccess: function(response){ Whatever you want to do}
}
request.send();
```

You could also use the Request.JSON object, which automatically decodes the response into a Json object.